# Compare a new list with existing list in java and create a difference list and delete the item from old if not present in new

Tags: java, list

I have a new list which contains

```
102
103
105
108
```

And an existing list which contains

```
102
104
105
108
109
```

want to make a list of all the items present on new list and and delete the items from old list that are not present in the new list.

Basically I need a list 1 which contains,

```
102
103
105
108
```

And another list which I need to delete from existing contains:

```
104
109
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting us know. What have you tried? What is your question? You can't just dump requirements here and expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Hints. Your final list is the "difference" between the second and the first. Java class `Set` has a difference operation.

Comment: The first one is called "intersection" for sets. The definition can be extended to lists as well, and some libraries support it out of the box, e.g. `org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.intersection()`. The second one can be done using [`Collection.retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Can't you just delete from the existing list, and thus the existing list becomes your "list1"?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using standard `List.removeAll()` method on a copy of the list.

```
List<Integer> newList = Arrays.asList(102, 103, 105, 108);
List<Integer> oldList = Arrays.asList(102, 104, 105, 108, 109);

List<Integer> deleted = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
deleted.removeAll(newList);
System.out.println(deleted);
```

Output

```
[104, 109]
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(102, 104, 105, 108, 109).removeAll(Arrays.asList(102, 103, 105, 108)));` ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work,

```
    List<Integer> newList = Arrays.asList(102,103,105,108); 
    List<Integer> exstList = Arrays.asList(102,104,105,108,109);
    List<Integer> deleList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int a : exstList){
        if(!newList.contains(a)){
            deleList.add(a);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newList); //as it is new list.
    System.out.println(deleList);// diff list
```